# Identify the source process and/or app from an output in the logcat

Tags: applications, logging, processes

When I plug my phone into my computer, I can see the logcat output in Android Studio. I recently noticed that whenever I start entering a password in a field designated for passwords (the ones that display '*' for any character), the phone prints a very concerning message to the console:

```
D/HwAutofillHelper: inputType is password, now record
```

Since it is an Honor Phone, I suppose `Hw` is short for Huawei?

Nevertheless, I'd like to know if there is a way to find out what process produced this output and what app it belongs to?

Comment: Based on on the Internet search result for `HwAutofillHelper` I would assume that this class exists only on Huawei devices (all references were related to Huawei devices). As the log entry can be produced by multiple apps, I would assume that it is a system framework that is active in every app. Would be interesting to see the code of this class...

Answer (score 4):

Logcat can show the process ID (PID) that outputs the log message.

- For [command-line](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#outputFormat): `adb logcat` will use `threadtime` by default, which shows the PID
- For [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running):

  1. Open the **Logcat** window
  2. From the toolbar (on the left-side), click the **Logcat Header** (cogwheel) button

     - If the toolbar is not shown, click the **Show Options Menu** (cogwheel) button on the top-right corner, then choose **Show Toolbar**
  3. On **Configure Logcat Header** dialog, check **Show process and thread IDs**, then press **OK**

By default, logcat will show the log in the following [format](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#format):

```
date time PID-TID/package priority/tag: message
```

With the PID, it is possible to identify the source with [`ps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command with `-p` flag to pinpoint the source, i.e. `adb shell ps -p [PID]`. The command will show the package name or the executable name.

---

#### Example

The logcat returned the following message

```
2020-07-08 22:06:16.002 18510-18510/? I/ScreenEventHandler: Received Broadcast ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

The PID is 18510.

Calling `adb shell ps -p 18510` returned the following

```
USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE   RSS   WCHAN            PC  NAME
u0_a107   18510 15708 1006092 44320 sys_epoll_ 00000000 S com.asksven.betterbatterystats
```

Thus, the message was written by `com.asksven.betterbatterystats` (BetterBatteryStats)

Comment: Further idea: getting the APK and browsing/reverse-engineering it to pinpoint the class name and the exact line in the code.